# Using a resource image in a library different from the main project

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources, .net-assembly

I have a WPF program with two libraries

[image]

now inside I have a gray resource background both in the main program and HelperLib. But additionally in the HelperLib I have a red background I want to use.

[image]

Now when I want to change the background of a window with:

```
 switch (bubbleType)
  {
    case eBubbleType.ERROR:
      bw.btText.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/gradientWallpaper_RED.jpg"))); <-----I want to use this one 
      break;

    default:
      bw.btText.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/gradientWallpaper.jpg")));
      break;
  }
```

but I get an image not found exception on the RED image but not on the other one.
I suspect that, when using the gray gradient it's not using the one in the lib but the one in the main program since I see that the resource is related to the assembly not to the project.
Both images have the same properties as in picture:

[image]

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use a [Resource File Pack Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) with the name of the referenced assembly:

```
new Uri(
  "pack://application:,,,/HelperLib;component/Resources/Images/gradientWallpaper_RED.jpg")
```